# Recreate Animation For a Hamburger menu icon with Just Surfaces

Tags: famo.us

How would one recreate the hamburger animation, using just surfaces. Please see attached link

http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/delightful-details.html#delightful-details-delightful-details

Comment: Rotate both surfaces and fade in the arrow while fadding out the hamburger. If you need more I can find my code example. I've got this and i have input with floating placeholder from the paper style but the pulsing click effect is beyond my reach for now.

Comment: @aintnorest It's not rotation + fade because the lines of the hamburger become side lines for the arrow. This should be SVG animation or something similar. I'm looking at it.